# Force Perl to work in 32-bit mode

Tags: perl, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit

We have an old Perl application. Recently we moved to a new server which runs 64-bit Ubuntu. 
Old application uses pack/unpack functions and bitwise operations and now it fails because bitwise operations return 64-bit integers instead of 32-bit.

Is there a way to force perl into 32-bit mode?
If not, is there a way to install 32-bit perl on 64-bit machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to force perl into 32-bit mode?

No, but you could switch to using the correct (portable) pack/unpack patterns and using `& 0xFFFFFFFF` where appropriate when bit twiddling.

> If not, is there a way to install 32-bit perl on 64-bit machine?

From `INSTALL`:

Natively 64-bit systems need neither -Duse64bitint nor -Duse64bitall. On these systems, it might be the default compilation mode, and there is currently no guarantee that passing no use64bitall option to the Configure process will build a 32bit perl. Implementing -Duse32bit* options is planned for a future release of perl.

So the answer is: maybe, but probably not.

Comment: Yes, sure I can change the code... But the application is quite large and it will probably take lots of time to find all places where code needs to be changed. And then it's always possible that I miss something and then will get hard-to-catch bugs.
So, I was looking for a simple alternative. Maybe running Perl with some command-line switch or some Perl command...
If nothing else work, I'll need to change source code, but I prefer not to.

Comment: @user610060, It really doesn't matter how much you need it, it still doesn't exist. The only option would be to use a 32-bit build of Perl.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you can install 32-bit packages by suffixing the package name with :i386.  At least this worked for me when installing a library.

$ sudo apt-get install libelf1:i386

I don't know if this works with non-libraries, as there would likely be filename and path conflicts.  With libraries, 32-bit and 64-bit libraries are packaged to fall into separate directories.