# Convert 64 bit value to 32 bit value in perl

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

How to  convert 64 bit value to 32 bit value in perl

for 32-bit perl

```
perl -e "use integer;print 88864420<<8"
```

output:

```
1274455040
```

for 64 bit perl

```
perl -e "use integer;print 88864420<<8"
22749291520
```

But i want the result as 32 bit value even in 64 bit perl.
So please help me in converting the value to 32 bit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6931686/223226

Answer (score 4):

Simply mask off excessive bits:

```
my $result = (88864420 << 8) & 0xFFFF_FFFF;
print $result;
```

Comment: @amon thank you very much. It worked :-)
Could you please explain how it works?